# How to get more than 100 results from GraphQL

Tags: python, json, python-requests, graphql

I am trying to receive the token pair data using GraphQL for every token pair on Uniswap 2.0. When I run my code I only get 100 results, but there are 1800+ that I need to retrieve. I have changed the query a few times, but regardless of how I change it there always seems to be a cap on the data for 100 pairs. How can I get the data for all the pairs?

```
import requests

query = """{
  pairs(orderBy: reserveUSD, orderDirection: asc) {
    id
    token0 {
      id
      symbol
      totalLiquidity
      totalSupply
    }
    token1 {
      id
      symbol
      totalLiquidity
      totalSupply
    }
    reserveUSD
    reserve0
    reserve1
    totalSupply
    volumeUSD
  }
}"""

url = 'https://api.thegraph.com/subgraphs/name/uniswap/uniswap-v2'
r = requests.post(url, json = {"query": query})#"{\n  pairs(first: 10, where: {reserveUSD_gt: \"1000000\", volumeUSD_gt: \"50000\"}, orderBy: reserveUSD, orderDirection: desc) {\n    id\n    token0 {\n      id\n      symbol\n    }\n    token1 {\n      id\n      symbol\n    }\n    reserveUSD\n    volumeUSD\n  }\n}\n","variables":None}) 
#print(r.text)
json_data = json.loads(r.text)
print(len(json_data['data']['pairs']))
```

Comment: This isn't really a general GraphQL question. It is up to the API you are querying to expose a way to request a specific number of results, and the API could always have a hard maximum where you are required to make multiple requests. Do you have links to documentation around the schema of this API?

Comment: This is a link to the [documention](https://uniswap.org/docs/v2/API/overview/) and this is a link to the [sandbox](https://thegraph.com/explorer/subgraph/uniswap/uniswap-v2?query=Example%20query)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can query up to 1000 results. Just need to add `"first"` into the query. If there are more than 1000 results then first do query `#1` and then run the second one, where you can use the skip function to skip 1000 that you already got.

```
{
  pairs(first: 1000, orderBy: reserveUSD, orderDirection: asc) {
    id
    token0 {
      id
      symbol
      totalLiquidity
      totalSupply
    }
    token1 {
      id
      symbol
      totalLiquidity
      totalSupply
    }
    reserveUSD
    reserve0
    reserve1
    totalSupply
    volumeUSD
  }
}
```